# Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2': package 'ggplot2' was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it Execution halted

Tags: r, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm really stuck and need some help.

After installing R 4.0.2, I'm getting this error message on R visualizations in Power BI Desktop which were previously working

```
"Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2':
 package 'ggplot2' was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it.
 Execution halted"
```

I already tried to:

```
reinstall R 4.0.2

reinstall RStudio

reinstall ggplot2 

reinstall all packages

reinstall Power BI Desktop. My version is August-2020
```

Still it does not work.

Considerations:

```
My visualizations were working well before I installed R 4.0.2

My visualizations are working well on other PCs

When I run the code on RStudio I don't get any error
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to go here:  https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/support/, but some guesses:

When you did the reinstall, you didn't clean up the old one, so you now have a mix of old and new versions of things.  If you can run R code, run

```
system.file(package="ggplot2")
```

That's where it is finding the bad version of `ggplot2`.  Get rid of it, and reinstall.  If that's not enough, run

```
.libPaths()
```

in the broken copy of R.  Completely eradicate every directory mentioned there, and reinstall R and all of your contributed packages.  (I don't use Power BI, so this might also require you to wipe out some part of it:  do so, and reinstall it.)

After all of this, run

```
packageDescription("ggplot2")
```

In the last line (or close to it) of what gets printed, you should see something like this:

```
Built: R 4.0.2; ; 2020-07-16 22:49:23 UTC; unix
```

If you see that it was built before 4.0.2, then either you missed deleting something, or you (or Microsoft) reinstalled some old version.  Then it's probably time to contact that URL above.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've also asked it in PBI commmunity, but tipically here I get a better/faster answer. I have proceeded as you suggested, and in fact I had a mix of different versions of packages. Now I'm on version 4.0.2. Unfortunately, the error on Power BI Desktop persists.